# Hard anodized wok without scratch-resistant coating?

Tags: wok

After many years our current wok is dying.  It did not have the non-stick coating, and we continue to not want non-stick coating on our wok.  But every time I search for "hard anodized wok without non-stick coating" I get 10,000 listings for hard anodized woks WITH non-stick coating.

Can anyone give me some suggestions for what we are looking for?  Does it just not exist any more?

Comment: Have you tried changing your search? something like - hard anodized wok -nonstick ? Search engines can't always tell that when you say "without" they mean "does not have", but if you say -nonstick it will exclude results that include the term "nonstick"... it won't necessarily catch everything but it should help somewhat. When I use that search, I get results that include: https://www.amazon.com/Crystal-Diamond-Nano-Anodized-16-8inch/dp/B01CJ9Q5WQ

Comment: Catija, thanks but not helpful, I think all the negatives got you confused -- saying "nonstick" will search for woks with a nonstick coating.  That is the opposite of what I want.  Saying "not non-stick" just brings up more nonstick choices, the search just ignores the word "not".

Comment: No,  adding a - before a term *excludes* it from the search. so if you search "hard anodized wok **-nonstick**" (without the quotes) it will *exclude* any page with the word "nonstick" on it.

Comment: Try searching for traditional woks instead.

Comment: Catija, thank you, didn't understand (or see) the - sign.  

Did not have time yesterday to do more searching.  Will try again, and report back.

Comment: Your title and question body don't match. The title doesn't make sense

Comment: Chris H...  there is non-stick, and there is non-stick coating.  Maybe?  I don't know, what I do know is we just have put to rest a hard anodized wok without the non-stick coating that didn't cause us problems with clean up.

Comment: you can remove the coating with sandpaper and elbow grease, steel wool to repolish.

Comment: I'd strongly recommend getting a good steel wok over aluminum.